# an emacs command to open a new instance of emacs

Tags: debugging, emacs, initialization, command

How can I make a cross-platform emacs command that opens another instance of emacs with -q option?

The reason why I need such a command is that it would be easy to modify the command to make it open another instance of emacs with -q and -l option so that the new instance loads an el file that I am editing with the old instance.

Comment: Step back.  Explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If emacs is in your path, you could do that with `meta-x shell` and then `emacs -d`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
(defun start-emacs-q ()
  (interactive)
  (start-process "Emacs" nil
         (executable-find "emacs") "-q"))
```